# Realign indexes to a changed python collection

Tags: python

I have a collection of data and a variable containing indexes to some of them.
A filtering operation is applied on the data that eliminates a subset of the data.
I want to shift the indexes so that they refer to the updated collection of data (eliminating indexes to deleted instances).

I'm using the implementation in the function below. I'm also posting the code I used to validate that it works.
Is there a quick & fast way to do the index realignment via the core libraries or a better way in general?

```py
import random

def align_index(wanted_idx, mask):
    """
    Function to align a set of indexes to a collection after deletions,
    indicated with a mask
    Arguments:
    wanted_idx: List of desired integer indexes prior to deletion
    mask: Binary mask, where 1's indicate elements that survive deletion
    Returns:
    List of integer indexes to (surviving) desired elements, post-deletion
    """
    # rebuild indexes: remove dangling
    new_idx = [idx for (i, idx) in enumerate(wanted_idx) if mask[idx]]
    # mark deleted
    not_mask = [int(not m) for m in mask]
    # cumsum deleted regions
    realigned_idx = [k-sum(not_mask[:k+1]) for k in new_idx]
    return realigned_idx

# data
data = [random.randint(0,500) for _ in range(1000)]
rng = list(range(len(data)))

for _ in range(1000):
    # random data deletion / request
    wanted_idx = random.sample(rng, random.randint(5,100))
    del_index = random.sample(rng, random.randint(5, 100))

    # apply deletion
    mask = [int(i not in del_index) for i in range(len(data))]
    filtered_data = [data[i] for (i, m) in enumerate(mask) if m]

    realigned_index = align_index(wanted_idx, mask)

    # verify
    new_idx = [idx for (i, idx) in enumerate(wanted_idx) if mask[idx]]
    l1 = [data[k] for k in new_idx]
    l2 = [filtered_data[k] for k in realigned_index]
    assert l1 == l2
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, or why. But there's certainly some mistakes in the code, whatever it is. For example, you seem to use `k` both as a value for an 'index' as well as an index into the mask, which seems to make no sense. Can you provide a sample of input data and expected outputs (and what you get instead)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy it's quite trivial:

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.array(mask, dtype=np.bool)
new_idx = np.cumsum(mask, dtype=np.int64)
new_idx[mask] = -1
```

You shouldn't need to recompute `new_idx` unless more elements get deleted.

Then you can get the remapped index for old index `i` just by looking `new_idx[i]`. Or a whole array at once:

```
wanted_idx = np.array(wanted_idx, dtype=np.int64)
remapped_idx = new_idx[wanted_idx]
```

Note that deleted indices get assigned value `-1`. You can filter these out if you want:

```
remapped_idx = remapped_idx[remapped_idx >= 0]
```